# function f defined on [0, 1] with range contained in [−1, 3] such that there is c between f (0) and f (1) but no x in [0, 1] such that f (x) = c.

Tags: calculus

Sketch the graph of a function f defined on [0, 1] with range contained in [−1, 3] such that there is c between f (0) and f (1) but no x in [0, 1] such that f (x) = c.

I not sure I understand the question correctly, but base on the IVT, it must exist an x in the interval [0,1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IVT applies only to continuous functions. No continuous function exists satisfying the above condition. However the following function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}3x-1&x<\frac12\\ 3x&x\ge\frac12\end{array}\right.$$

Then there is no $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=1$.

[image]

Comment: isn't the function f defined on [0, 1] mean it is continuous?

Comment: No it just means that $f(x)$ is defined for every $x\in[0,1]$. See the example.